# Can I specify a default mapping source for unmapped members with AutoMapper?

Tags: automapper, automapper-6

I have a type that encapsulates a bunch of related data

```
class CollectionNoteDetails
{
    CollectionNote Note {get;set;}
    Customer SourceCustomer {get;set;}
    Customer DestinationCustomer {get;set;}
    Haulier Haulier{ get;set;}
}
```

and I want to flatten it

```
class CollectionNoteDto
{
    // using fields for brevity

    int Id;
    DateTime CollectionDate;
    // ... plus about 30 more props

    string SourceCustomerName;
    string DestinationCustomerName;
    string HaulierName;
}
```

there's about 30 properties on the DTO that come off the `CollectionNote`, and a few that come off the other entities. The other entities are easy to handle in the `CreateMap()` call:

```
CreateMap<CollectionNoteDetails, CollectionNoteDoc>(MemberList.Destination)
    .ForMember(d => d.SourceCustomerName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.SourceCustomer.Name))
     .ForMember(d => d.DestinationCustomerName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.DestinationCustomer.Name))
     .ForMember(d => d.HaulierName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Haulier.Name));
```

... but is there an easy way to map the rest of the properties to the `Note` source property? Something like this made up method.

```
CreateMap<CollectionNoteDetails, CollectionNoteDoc>(MemberList.Destination)
   .MapAllByDefault(o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Note))
   // other explicit mappings here
   .ForMember(d => d.HaulierName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Haulier.Name));
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html

Answer (score 0):

You might need to [recognize a prefix](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#recognizing-pre-postfixes). The example from the documentation:

```
public class Source {
    public int frmValue { get; set; }
    public int frmValue2 { get; set; }
}
public class Dest {
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
}
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.RecognizePrefixes("frm");
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>();
});
```

On different matters, note that [flattening](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html) is automatically supported by automapper, which means that this code:

```
CreateMap<CollectionNoteDetails, CollectionNoteDoc>(MemberList.Destination)
    .ForMember(d => d.SourceCustomerName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.SourceCustomer.Name))
     .ForMember(d => d.DestinationCustomerName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.DestinationCustomer.Name))
     .ForMember(d => d.HaulierName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Haulier.Name));
```

is equivalent to:

```
CreateMap<CollectionNoteDetails, CollectionNoteDoc>(MemberList.Destination);
```